# How do you solve Laplace's equation for a parallel plate capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, greens-functions

I would like to find the analytic solution to the problem of two plates of opposite electric potential. I have already solved this numerically as shown in the picture below.

I'm also wondering what type of boundary conditions are present here. My usual methods of solving PDE's are integral transforms or finding separable solutions but this breaks down here.

Here's the problem:

$$
\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}(x,y) =0
$$
$$
\phi(x,d) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
V & |x|<l/2 \\
\mbox{undefined} & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
$$
\phi(x,0) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
-V & |x|<l/2 \\
\mbox{undefined} & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
$V$ is some positive constant.
$l$ is the length of the capacitor and $d$ is the plate separation.

$\phi \rightarrow 0 $ as $x$ or $y \rightarrow \infty $

[image]

Comment: You need to use conformal mapping techniques, look up conformal mapping for electrostatics.

Comment: Do you need an analytic solution for all of space (sans the boundaries of course)?  Or is there some specific spatial point in which you are interested?

Comment: I'd like the solution for all space ideally, however specific points would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for infinite plates is known. Now imagine that infinite plates are made of three segments: semi-infinite plates on the left, finite-size plates in the middle, and semi-infinite plates on the right. So if we have a solution for semi-infinite plates then we can easily figure out the contribution from the finite-size plates in the middle. The solution for semi-infinite plates can be obtained by conformal mapping techniques, it is available in standard textbooks.

Also, it looks like in "Classical Electromagnetic Theory" by Jack Vanderlinde a solution for a single finite size plate is worked out (also by conformal mapping); combining two such solutions one can obtain the field of a finite size capacitor.